# Is there a better way to split this string using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I've got some longitude\latitude coordinates bunched together in a string that I'd like to split into longitude\latitude pairs.  Thanks to stackoverflow I've been able to come up with the some linq that will split it into a multidimensional string array.  Is there a way to split the string directly into an object that accepts the longitude latitude vs a string array then create the object?

```
string segment = "51.54398, -0.27585;51.55175, -0.29631;51.56233, -0.30369;51.57035, -0.30856;51.58157, -0.31672;51.59233, -0.3354"

string[][] array = segment.Split(';').Select(s => s.Split(',')).ToArray();
foreach (string[] pair in array)
{
//create object here
}
```

Comment: There is (almost?) never a good way to split a string using linq. That said, System.Text.RegularExpressions is what you want

Comment: What's that `-0.3354", "London:484"` at the end of your string?

Comment: @sehe: Using a regular expression for such a trivial task is overkill.  If you know that the format of your input is constant and that it is easy to parse by splitting you *should* be using split instead of a regex.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry, some extra data in there.

Comment: @sehe Not a big fan of RegualrExpressions but I appreciate the answer.

Comment: @NullReference Added **[an answer with demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10080471/85371)**. See it **[live on IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/1HCvu)**

Comment: You know what they say about regular expressions... now you've got two problems.

Comment: @EdS. Opinions vary. I don't understand the need to spend two comments basically repeating your view. Obviously, parsing with the regex does input checking beyond what splitting does. Let the OP decide. **Edit** Note also how my answer appears to be the only one that worries about number parsing at all, not assuming US culture, e.g.

Comment: @sehe: It's not an opinion, it is a fact.  If you know that you have two numbers at a known position in a string then you are unnecessarily complicating things by using a regular expression.  I don't understand your culture argument, `double.Parse` can account for that just fine.

Comment: @EdS. Ok, then, translated to your jargon: "Facts vary". Whatever :) `double.Parse` might be able to account for things, but _nobody did_

Comment: This regular expression will group the string into pairs `(?<pair>(?<lat>[\d\.-]*), (?<lng>[\d\.-]*))`. I don't know .NET regular expressions well enough to use the groups, though. :)

Comment: @sehe: Facts do not vary actually, and thank you for proving my point for me Jan.  Localization may not be a requirement for this project.  Not every piece of software needs to run on a non US English local.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are close. Something like this might help:

```
var pairSequence = segment.Split(';')
        .Select(s => s.Split(','))
        .Select(a => new { Lat = double.Parse(a[0]), Long = double.Parse(a[1]) });
```

Comment: @Alex Of course, depends on the type you actually need. You get the idea.

Comment: Damn.  Was in the process of writing almost something identical.  Kudos.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have a `Coordinate` class with a `public Coordinate(double x, double y)` constructor, you can do this:

```
Coordinate[] result = segment
    .Split(';')
    .Select(s => s.Split(','))
    .Select(a => new Coordinate(x: double.Parse(a[0], NumberStyles.Number),
                                y: double.Parse(a[1], NumberStyles.Number))
    .ToArray();
```

or equally

```
var query = from item in segment.Split(';')
            let parts = item.Split(',')
            let x = double.Parse(parts[0], NumberStyles.Number)
            let y = double.Parse(parts[1], NumberStyles.Number)
            select new Coordinate(x, y);

Coordinate[] result = query.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
public class GeoCoordinates {
  public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
  public decimal Longitude { get; set; }

  public GeoCoordinates( string latLongPair ) {
    decimal lat, lng;
    var parts = latLongPair.Split( new[] { ',' } );
    if( decimal.TryParse( parts[0], out lat ) &&
      decimal.TryParse( parts[1], out lng ) ) {
      Latitude = lat;
      Longitude = lng;
    } else {
      // you could set some kind of "ParseFailed" or "Invalid" property here
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can create a collection of GeoCoordinate classes thusly:

```
var coords = segment.Split( new[] {';'} ).Select( x => new GeoCoordinates( x ) );
```

Comment: Heh...StackOverflow can be quite the race, can't it?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a ‘somewhat’ nice snippet showing:

- precompiled regexen
- LINQ to anonymous type projection
- Culture-aware (**correct**) number parsing and printing

*You would want to extract certain code (e.g. the number parsing) in real life.*

See it **[live on Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/1HCvu)**.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Globalization;

namespace SODemo
{
    class MainClass
    {
        private static readonly CultureInfo CInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            string segment = "51.54398, -0.27585;51.55175, -0.29631;51.56233, -0.30369;51.57035, -0.30856;51.58157, -0.31672;51.59233, -0.3354";

            var re = new Regex(@"\s*(?<lat>[-+]?[0-9.]+),\s*(?<lon>[-+]?[0-9.]+)\s*;", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            var locations = re.Matches(segment).Cast<Match>().Select(m => new 
            {
                Lat  = decimal.Parse(m.Groups["lat"].Value, CInfo),
                Long = decimal.Parse(m.Groups["lon"].Value, CInfo),
            });

            foreach (var l in locations)
                Console.WriteLine(l);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{ Lat = 51,54398, Long = -0,27585 }
{ Lat = 51,55175, Long = -0,29631 }
{ Lat = 51,56233, Long = -0,30369 }
{ Lat = 51,57035, Long = -0,30856 }
{ Lat = 51,58157, Long = -0,31672 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it a necessity that you use LINQ? You can do it all with standard string splitting functionality:

```
string[] pairsOfCoords = segment.Split(';');
List<CoordsObject> listOfCoords = new List<CoordsObject>();
foreach (string str in pairsOfCoords)
{
  string[] coords = str.Split(',');
  CoordsObject obj = new CoordsObject(coords[0], coords[1]);
  listOfCoords.Add(obj);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but look how much cleaner it is with linq.  :)

Comment: @RobertP: Well I suppose that is subjective.  This looks pretty simple and clean to me.

Answer (score 1):

I might add a bit more. Thanks to dtb for the start, upvoted. If you break your parsing function out, you can more cleanly handle error conditions, such as wrong number of elements in your array, or things that don't parse to a decimal.

```
Coordinate[] result = segment
.Split(';')
.Select(s => s.Split(','))
.Select(BuildCoordinate)
.ToArray();

Coordrinate BuildCoordinate(string[] coords)
{
    if(coords.Length != 2)
        return null;

    return new Coordinate(double.Parse(a[0].Trim(), double.Parse(a[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some tasks are just easier to solve the old way:

```
var split = segment.Split();
var coordinates = new List<Coordinate>(split.Length);
foreach(string s in split)
{
    coordinates.Add(new Coordinate(s));
}
```